# Perl security, the print statement?

Tags: perl, security, exploit

I don't know perl at all, but I need to change an exitsting program to give a clearer debug output.

This is the statement:

`print $lfh "$ts\t$tid\t$msg\n";`

where $msg will be created by joining the arguments of the function like this:

`my $msg = join( "\t", @_ );`

Somewhere in $msg I would like to add one of the command line arguments the user has supplied when calling the program. Is that risk for an exploit if printed to stdout?

Note also that $lfh will be taken from an environment variable (set by the script itself earlier on) if it is to write to a file, like this:

`open my $lfh, ">>", $ENV{GL_LOGFILE}`

The info I could find on perl security says nothing about the print statement, so maybe I'm just completely paranoid, but better safe than sorry...

Comment: Environment could be considered as user input, so it needs some sort of sanitization. Using three argument for `open` is a plus. If STDOUT output is not subject to execution, it should not pose a threat.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arbitrary data to `print`, and it won't break. However:

- printing to a file handle may go through various IO layers like encodings. Not all data may be valid for these layers. E.g. encoding layers will either use a substitution character or terminate the script when handed invalid data.
- Perl's `print` doesn't care about control characters like NULs, backspaces, or carriage returns and just passes them through. Depending on how the output is viewed, it might look jumbled or could break the viewing application. Example: User input is equal to the string `"\rHAHA"`. When you print `"something$userinput"`, you might see `HAHAthing` when displayed on the console, because the carriage returns places the cursor in the 1st column. If the user input contains newlines, your output records could be broken up, e.g. `"foo${userinput}bar"` might become the two lines `foo` and `bar`.
- If the input is condidential information, the output will be confidential as well, so you should make sure that the output can't be viewed by anyone. E.g. displaying the output including debug information on a web page could allow attackers to obtain more information about your system.